# Update WebcamTexture by Networkview

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam, rpc

I've made a project using the camera device and works fine. But now, I want to send the webcamtexture from one device to others. Just like a networkview works with transform, but I know it's not that easy.

How can I send the webcamtexture to watch it from another connected devices?

Thank you.

Comment: The frames would need to be delta compressed by a video codec, in order to achieve what you want. You can consider using ffmpeg as a plugin for unity and delta encode the images to a stream that you send to the other device via a Network View, however that might be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that using Networkview, you can try to use third party network library and send the compressed image data to client every frame. 
Maybe a bit laggy, but should work.